# c# MVC Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv

I'm generating a CSV file and trying to send it down the wire using MVC but I keep getting the `Illegal characters in path` exception.

I've tried using different ways, like quoting the columns, changing \n to `Environment.NewLine` but the cause of the problem still eludes me.

**Controller code:**

```
string csv = "";
csv = "Name, Sales, Qty, Cost, Profit" + "\n";
foreach (var item in model.ReportResults.Items) {
    csv += item.ToCsv();
}

return File(csv, "text/csv", "myfile.csv");
```

**ToCsv method:**

```
internal string ToCsv() 
{
    return "" + Name + "" + "," + Sales.ToString() + "," + Qty.ToString() + "," + Cost.ToString() + "," + Profit.ToString() + "\n";
}
```

**Snapshot of the CSV file that's generated:**

```
Name, Sales, Qty, Cost, Profit
Tyranids,4979.29,182,3375.00,1604.29
Space Marines,2127.88,87,948.09,1179.79
Tau Empire,1584.01,40,0.00,1584.01
Eldar,1164.04,44,925.38,238.66
Imperial Guard,1005.79,34,790.10,215.69
```

Comment: What are you trying to do when the exception is thrown? What does the stack trace look like? What does your `File` method do?

Comment: I'm returning File as an ActionResult in an MVC Action

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload of `File()`.  `csv` is a string, [which tells it that you're looking for a file by that name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593.aspx).  Naturally, the entirety of your CSV data isn't a valid filename, hence the error.

Instead of a string, you want to return a `byte[]` as the actual in-memory data of the "file."  Perhaps something like this:

```
var csvBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv);
return File(csvBytes, "text/csv", "myfile.csv");
```

(Or whatever character encoding you want to use.)

Comment: File(string, string, string) is a file on the server isn't it?

Comment: @Smithy: Correct, the first parameter would be the name of the existing server-side file to be loaded into memory and returned.

Comment: *slaps head* doh! Works great, will mark you Accepted in 7 mins. Many thanks :)